# Using racket txexpr to render a list

Tags: html, racket

I'm trying to render a list of items in racket using `txexpr`:

```
(define (item-list items)
  (if (empty? items)
      (txexpr 'p empty '("No items to display."))
      (txexpr* 'ul empty
               (for ([item items])
                 (txexpr 'li empty (list (cadr item)))))))
```

My test code looks like this:

```
(module+ test
   (test-case "item-list will return a default message if the item list is empty"
     (define result "<p>No items to display.</p>")
     (define no-items empty)
     (check-equal? (xexpr->html (rule-list no-items)) result))
  (test-case "item-list will return an unordered list of each item"
    (define result "<ul><li>email address</li><li>phone number</li></ul>")
    (define two-items '((1 "email address") (2 "phone number")))
    (check-equal? (xexpr->html (rule-list two-items)) result)))
```

When I run the tests I get the following error on the second test:

```
txexpr*: contract violation
  expected: txexpr-elements?
  given: '(#<void>)
```

I'm now stumped.  How do I get the list of items to render?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it's likely that you need to change `(for ([item items])` to `(for/list ([item items])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the thing to note is that at some point what you end up with a list of lists.

```
(define (item-list items)
  (if (empty? items)
      (txexpr 'p empty '("No items to display."))
      (txexpr 'ul empty
              (for/list ([item items])
                (quasiquote (li (unquote (cadr item))))))))
```

This means that I needed to quote the rule list correctly and the data structure became comprehendible to `txexpr`.  For instance, running a two-item list

```
(item-list (list '(1 "one") '(2 "two")))
```

gets you a data structure like this:

```
'(ul (li "one") (li "two"))
```

Hope that helps others.